# runST and function composition

Tags: haskell, function-composition

Why does this typecheck:

```
runST $ return $ True
```

While the following does not:

```
runST . return $ True
```

GHCI complains:

```
Couldn't match expected type `forall s. ST s c0'
            with actual type `m0 a0'
Expected type: a0 -> forall s. ST s c0
  Actual type: a0 -> m0 a0
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `return'
In the expression: runST . return
```

Comment: If `($)` could be given a depedently typed signature as `($) : forall (a : *) (b : a -> *) . ((x : a) -> b x) -> (x : a) -> b x` it would work without GHC tricks, and similarly for `(.)`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The short answer is that type inference doesn't always work with higher-rank types. In this case, it is unable to infer the type of `(.)`, but it type checks if we add an explicit type annotation:

```
> :m + Control.Monad.ST
> :set -XRankNTypes
> :t (((.) :: ((forall s0. ST s0 a) -> a) -> (a -> forall s1. ST s1 a) -> a -> a) runST return) $ True
(((.) :: ((forall s0. ST s0 a) -> a) -> (a -> forall s1. ST s1 a) -> a -> a) runST return) $ True :: Bool
```

The same problem also happens with your first example, if we replace `($)` with our own version:

```
> let app f x = f x
> :t runST `app` (return `app` True)
<interactive>:1:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `forall s. ST s t0'
                with actual type `m0 t10'
    Expected type: t10 -> forall s. ST s t0
      Actual type: t10 -> m0 t10
    In the first argument of `app', namely `return'
    In the second argument of `app', namely `(return `app` True)'
```

Again, this can be solved by adding type annotations:

```
> :t (app :: ((forall s0. ST s0 a) -> a) -> (forall s1. ST s1 a) -> a) runST (return `app` True)
(app :: ((forall s0. ST s0 a) -> a) -> (forall s1. ST s1 a) -> a) runST (return `app` True) :: Bool
```

What is happening here is that there is a special typing rule in GHC 7 which only applies to the standard `($)` operator. Simon Peyton-Jones explains this behavior in [a reply on the GHC users mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org/msg18923.html):

> This is a motivating example for type inference that can deal with 
>   impredicative types.  Consider the type of `($)`:
>
> ```
> ($) :: forall p q. (p -> q) -> p -> q
> ```
>
> In the example we need to instantiate `p` with `(forall s. ST s a)`, and that's  what
>   impredicative polymorphism means: instantiating a type variable with a
>   polymorphic type.
>
> Sadly, I know of no system of reasonable complexity that can typecheck
>   [this] unaided.  There are plenty of complicated systems, and I have
>   been a co-author  on papers on at least two, but they are all Too
>   Jolly Complicated to live in  GHC.  We did have an implementation of
>   boxy types, but I took it out when  implementing the new typechecker. 
>   Nobody understood it.
>
> However, people so often write
>
> ```
> runST $ do ...
> ```
>
> that in GHC 7 I implemented a special typing rule, just for infix uses of `($)`. Just think of `(f $ x)` as a new
>   syntactic form, with the obvious typing rule, and away you go.

Your second example fails because there is no such rule for `(.)`.

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make sense now.

Answer (score 36):

The `runST $ do { ... }` pattern is so common, and the fact that it normally wouldn't type-check is so annoying, that GHC included some `ST`-specific type-checking hacks to make it work. Those hacks are probably firing here for the `($)` version, but not the `(.)` version.

Comment: Interesting point. It is probably enough to simply drop the ($) as soon as it is seen that it is applied to 2 arguments. Should be easily verifiable by replacing it with a custom function that does the same as ($), and look if the type checker would complain then.

Comment: @Ingo: Yep, ```let app f x = f x in runST `app` (return `app` True)``` fails to type check. Interesting.

Comment: @Hammar: This means, GHC apparently drops the $ despite this is not quite correct with higher rank types.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The first snippet wouldn't normally typecheck, however, GHC has a special rule for `runST $ whatever`, but not for `runST . foo`.

Comment: And not for `($) runST (return True)` which doesn't typecheck either

Answer (score 3):

The messages are a bit confusing the point (or so I feel).
Let me rewrite your code:

```
runST (return True)   -- return True is ST s Bool
(runST . return) True  -- cannot work
```

Another way to put this is that the monomorphic `m0 a0` (the result of return, if it would get an a0) cannot be unified with (forall s.ST s a).

Comment: This does typecheck: `unsafePerformIO . return $ True`

Comment: @Ingo: You're parsing the two examples wrong. `runST $ return $ True` is `($) runST (($) return True)`, and `runST . return $ True` is `($) ((.) runST return) True`. They would do the same thing in the absence of rank-2 types.

Comment: @ehird - You're right, I forgot the dot. (Hey, that rhymes ...)