# GHC violates the identity laws?

Tags: haskell, ghc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [runST and function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition)

I've encountered a weird code segment that GHC fails to type-check correctly when composed with `id`.  I'm pretty sure this is a GHC bug, but I wanted to check by here first before filing a bug report with the GHC developers.  I'll begin with the working code:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

v :: V.Vector Int
v = V.create $ MV.replicate 1 0
```

This creates a new vector in the ST monad and works just fine:

```
>>> v
fromList [0]
```

The bug occurs when I compose `V.create` with `id`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

v :: V.Vector Int
v = id . V.create $ MV.replicate 1 0
```

... failing with the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `forall s.
                              GHC.ST.ST s (MV.MVector s a0)'
            with actual type `m0 (MV.MVector
                                    (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) a1)'
In the return type of a call of `MV.replicate'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `MV.replicate 1 0'
In the expression: id . V.create $ MV.replicate 1 0
```

However, if I apply the `id` instead of composing it, then the code type-checks just fine:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

v :: V.Vector Int
v = id $ V.create $ MV.replicate 1 0
```

Based on that, I'm guessing that something about composition with `id` causes GHC to accidentally generalize or specialize `V.create`, causing it to trigger a type mismatch with `MV.replicate`.  However, beyond that I'm stuck because the type error is a little bit over my head.

It's also not a problem with the monomorphism restriction.  The problem persists even when I enable the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` flag.

This is a pretty weird problem because I would expect `id . f == f`.  Also, the right identity law fails, too, as the following example also fails to type-check:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

v :: V.Vector Int
v = V.create . id $ MV.replicate 1 0
```

This is using GHC version 7.4.1 and `vector-0.9.1`.

Comment: Strictly, `forall s. ST s something` can't be arguments to `($)` or `(.)`, but there are some special cases because e.g. `runST $ whatever` is so common. However, when composing (`(.)`) or adding another `($)`, these special cases usually don't work anymore. Use parentheses if you don't want to rely on them.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition

Comment: @Vitus That was exactly what I was looking for.  It looks like the GHC developers are aware of the issue.  It's pretty lame, but at least I know how to work around it.  How do I close this and mark it as a duplicate of that one?