# Haskell: map runST

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I have a binding for a type `[ST s (Int, [Int])]` and I am trying to apply `runST` to each element using map as follows:

```
name :: [ST s (Int, [Int])] --Of Course there is a real value here
map runST name
```

This gives me an error message

```
Couldn't match expected type `forall s. ST s b0'
    with actual type `ST s0 (Int, [Int])'
Expected type: [forall s. ST s b0]
  Actual type: [ST s0 (Int, [Int])]
In the second argument of `map', namely `name'
In the expression: map runST name
```

There must be something I am misunderstanding. I am aware of [runST and function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition), but am unsure if this applies.

Thanks for everyones time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each time you run a state transformer with `runST`, it operates on some local state that is separate from all other state transformers.  `runST` creates a *new* state type and calls its argument with that type.  So, for example, if you execute

```
let x = runST (return ())
    y = runST (return ())
in (x, y)
```

then the first `return ()` and second `return ()` will have different types: `ST s1 ()` and `ST s2 ()`, for some unknown types `s1` and `s2` that are created by `runST`.

You are trying to call `runST` with an argument that has state type `s`.  That is not the state type that `runST` creates, nor is any other type you can choose.  To call `runST`, you must pass an argument that can have *any* state type.  Here is an example:

```
r1 :: forall s. ST s ()
r1 = return ()
```

Because `r1` is polymorphic, its state can have any type, including whatever type is selected by `runST`.  You can map `runST` over a list of polymorphic `r1`s (with `-XImpredicativeTypes`):

```
map runST ([r1, r1] :: [forall t. ST t ()])
```

However, you cannot map `runST` over a list of non-polymorphic `r1`s.

```
map runST ([r1, r1] :: forall t. [ST t ()]) -- Not polymorphic enough
```

The type `forall t. [ST t ()]` says that all list elements have state type `t`.  But they need to all have independent state types because `runST` is called on each one.  That is what the error message means.

If it is okay to give the same state to all list elements, then you can call `runST` once as shown below.  The explicit type signature is not required.

```
runST (sequence ([r1, r1] :: forall t. [ST t ()]))
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `name` is not polymorphic enough. Your statement

```
name :: [ST s (Int, [Int])]
```

means 'a list of stateful computations returning (Int, [Int]) which have *exactly the same* `s`'. But look at the type of `runST`:

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

This type means 'a function which takes a stateful computation where `s` *can be anything you can ever imagine*'. These types of computation is not the same thing. And finally:

```
map runST :: [forall s. ST s a] -> [a]
```

You see, your list should contain more polymorphic values than it do now. `s` type could be different in each element of the list, it may not be the same type as in `name`. Change the type signature of `name`, and all should be OK. It may require some extensions to be enabled, but GHC should be able to tell you which ones.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to explain the reasoning for `runST`'s type:

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

And why it isn't like this simple one:

```
alternativeRunST :: ST s a -> a
```

Note that this `alternativeRunST` would had worked for your program.

`alternativeRunST` would also had allowed us to leak variables out of the `ST` monad:

```
leakyVar :: STRef s Int
leakyVar = alternativeRunST (newSTRef 0)

evilFunction :: Int -> Int
evilFunction x =
  alternativeRunST $ do
    val <- readSTRef leakyVar
    writeSTRef leakyVar (val+1)
    return (val + x)
```

Then you could go in ghci and do:

```
>>> map evilFunction [7,7,7]
[7,8,9]
```

`evilFunction` is not referentially transparent!

Btw, to try it out yourself here's the "bad ST" framework needed to run the code above:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe
newtype ST s a = ST { unST :: IO a } deriving Monad
newtype STRef s a = STRef { unSTRef :: IORef a }
alternativeRunST :: ST s a -> a
alternativeRunST = unsafePerformIO . unST
newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)
newSTRef = ST . liftM STRef . newIORef
readSTRef :: STRef s a -> ST s a
readSTRef = ST . readIORef . unSTRef
writeSTRef :: STRef s a -> a -> ST s ()
writeSTRef ref = ST . writeIORef (unSTRef ref)
```

The real `runST` doesn't allow us to construct such "evil" functions. How does it do it? It's kinda tricky, see below:

Trying to run:

```
>>> runST (newSTRef "Hi")
error:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `STRef s [Char]'
...

>>> :t runST
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
>>> :t newSTRef "Hi"
newSTRef "Hi" :: ST s (STRef s [Char])
```

`newSTRef "Hi"` doesn't fit `(forall s. ST s a)`. As can be also seen using an even simpler example, where GHC gives us a pretty nice error:

```
dontEvenRunST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> Int
dontEvenRunST = const 0

>>> dontEvenRunST (newSTRef "Hi")
<interactive>:14:1:
    Couldn't match type `a0' with `STRef s [Char]'
      because type variable `s' would escape its scope
```

Note that we can also write

```
dontEvenRunST :: forall a. (forall s. ST s a) -> Int
```

And it is equivalent to omitting the `forall a.` as we did before.

Note that the scope of `a` is larger than that of `s`, but in the case of `newSTRef "Hi"` its value should depend on `s`. The type system doesn't allow this.

Comment: @yairchu could you please elaborate why it fails with `dontEvenRunST` in a way it's explained here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types Every article I've seen always mentions that it's related to the state type mismatch between the argument and the return type, but you show that even if return type is something else (like `Int`) it still will not typecheck.