# Why there needs to be a $ in calls like "runSomeMonad $ do ..."?

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads, do-notation

Apparently the only possible interpretation of `runSomeMonad do ...` is `runSomeMonad (do ...)`. Why isn't the first variant allowed by the Haskell syntax? Is there some case where `foo do bar` could be actually ambiguous?

Comment: Not just do, `foo if bar then quux else baz` as well.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that you can have something like `runSomeMonad (do ...) x y z ...`.

Comment: @DavidYoung I don't see how the proposed grammar change would prevent that kind of thing.

Comment: Just a historical accident, as far as I know.

Comment: As of GHC 8.6.1, you can enable the [`BlockArguments` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-BlockArguments) to allow, among other things, `runSomeMonad do ...`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that you can observe this effect with not just `do`, but also `let`, `if`, `\`, `case`, the extensions `mdo` and `proc`…and the dread unary `-`. I cannot think of a case in which this is ambiguous *except* for unary `-`. Here’s how the grammar is defined in the [Haskell 2010 Language Report, §3: Expressions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html).

```
exp
    → infixexp :: [context =>] type
    | infixexp

infixexp
    → lexp qop infixexp
    | - infixexp
    | lexp

lexp
    → \ apat1 … apatn -> exp
    | let decls in exp
    | if exp [;] then exp [;] else exp
    | case exp of { alts }
    | do { stmts }
    | fexp

fexp
    → [fexp] aexp

aexp
    → ( exp )
    | …
```

There just happens to be no case defined in `fexp` (function application) or `aexp` (literal expression) that allows an unparenthesised `lexp` (lambda, `let`, etc.). I would consider this a bug in the grammar.

Fixing this would also remove the need for [the `$` typing hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469942/246886).

Comment: Years ago, I built GHC from sources with the grammar modified in this sort of way, and it indeed seemed not to break anything (e.g, it could successfully rebuild itself). I especially liked the look of calls which pass arguments to the block, like `withOpenFile path \ handle -> do ...`

Comment: @Brandon: I suppose you wouldn't have the time to push this modification as an e.g. `{-# LANGUAGE UnparenthesizedLayoutHeralds #-}` extension?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Maybe with a slightly shorter name…

Comment: What, _shorter_? Whenever I type `MultiParamTypeClasses` I'm so delighted that Emacs' auto-complete is disabled in "comments", I'd love more of that kind of fun...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Solution: type `XMulti`, hit M-/ to `dabbrev-expand` from the compiler error “perhaps you meant `-XMultiParamTypeClasses`”, then delete the `X`. :P