# Mixing IO w/ ST Monad - "type variable `s2' would escape its scope"

Tags: haskell, st-monad

I decided to simplify my code to see what conditions produced the error. I start with a simple nested "s" similar to `ST s (STArray s x y)` like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Applicative

data Foo s = Foo { foo::Bool }

newFoo :: ST s (Foo s)
newFoo = return $ Foo False
```

To test the state code, I run the following transformation:

```
changeFoo :: (forall s. ST s (Foo s)) -> ST s (Foo s)
changeFoo sf = do
   f <- sf
   let f' = Foo (not $ foo f)
   return f'
```

I would like to extract a value from the state while keeping the state, so the next step is to extract the Bool value:

```
splitChangeFoo :: (forall s. ST s (Foo s)) -> ST s (Bool,(Foo s))
splitChangeFoo sf = do
   f <- changeFoo sf
   let b = foo f
   return (b,f)
```

In order to extract that Bool I must use `runST`. My understanding is that this will create an additional state, which I specify by providing a `forall s.` in the return type:

```
extractFoo :: (forall s. ST s (Bool,(Foo s))) -> (forall s. (Bool,ST s ((Foo s))))
extractFoo sbf = (runST $ fst <$> sbf,snd <$> sbf)
```

The example above does compile without the final `forall` however in the circumstance I am trying to debug this is not possible. Regardless, in this case it compiles either way.

I am able to use the above code to chain multiple uses of the state together:

```
testFoo :: (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
testFoo = (b && b',sf')
   where
      (b,sf) = extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo newFoo
      (b',sf') = extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo sf
```

Now I try to throw IO into the mix and so I make use of the applicative fmap `<$>`. This does not compile: (NB. same problem if I use `fmap` or `>>= return` rather than `<$>`)

```
testBar :: IO (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
testBar = (\(b,sf) -> extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo sf) <$> testBar'
   where
      testBar' :: IO (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
      testBar' = return $ extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo newFoo
```

With the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `s0' with `s2'
  because type variable `s2' would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  a type expected by the context: ST s2 (Foo s2)
The following variables have types that mention s0
  sf :: ST s0 (Foo s0) (bound at src\Tests.hs:132:16)
Expected type: ST s2 (Foo s2)
  Actual type: ST s0 (Foo s0)
In the first argument of `splitChangeFoo', namely `sf'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `splitChangeFoo sf'
In the expression: extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo sf
```

I'm aware from this [SO question about ST function composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition) that not all possible uses of ST are accounted for by the compiler. To test this assumption I modified the above function to not use IO and simply pass the return value into a lambda:

```
testFooBar :: (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
testFooBar = (\(b,sf) -> extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo sf) testFooBar'
   where
      testFooBar' :: (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
      testFooBar' = extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo newFoo
```

Predictably this also does not compile with an identical error message.

This presents a challenge. I have a reasonable amount of IO that needs to interact with a set of deeply nested ST operations. It works perfectly fine for a single iteration, however I am not able to make further use of the return value.

Comment: What is the point of having something of type `(Bool, ST s (Foo s))`? Why not just have a `ST s (Bool, Foo s)`? It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. In response to "I have a reasonable amount of IO that needs to interact with a set of deeply nested ST operations": do your ST operations, call `runST` on the result, then do your `IO` operations. If they need to be interleaved, either introduce abstraction in the form of a monad transformer, or use `unsafeIOtoST` (if appropriate).

Comment: The ST operations run on their own thread in a continuous loop. Occasionally other threads need to interact with that state through channels. If I was to leave ST each iteration I would have to freeze/thaw 6x `STArray`s within my `ST s`, which would be much safer than `unsafeIOtoST`. This is undesirable for a lot of reasons. As far as I can tell there's no reason my example shouldn't type check. Even from a purely academic perspective, `testFoo` type checks while `testFooBar` does not. The only tangible difference is that `testFooBar` uses a lambda.

Comment: You probably need something like `testBar' :: IO (forall s. (Bool, ST s (Foo s)))` or `testBar' :: IO (Bool, forall s. ST s (Foo s))`. This requires impredicative types. I am not sure about what you are actually trying to achieve. If you need to interact with other threads, it might be simpler to convert `ST` into `IO`.

Comment: The `ST` monad lets you go in, do some mutable stuff, and come out again with a pure result. By design, you can't use it to repeatedly mutate stuff and return answers back to the caller. Only `IO` can do that. If you want multiple threads interacting through mutable state, `ST` is explicitly designed to _prevent_ that ever happening. You probably want `IO` (and possibly `STM`).

Comment: The purposes of using `STArray` was performance (constant time lookups). I decided to give `unsafeIOtoST` a go, seeing as I wanted to extract something from the ST for IO. That with this type signature change seemed to work: `extractFoo :: (forall s. ST s (Bool,(Foo s))) -> ((IO Bool,ST s ((Foo s))))`. Can't really see a downside...

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive The only downside is the "unsafe" part - you have to be extremely careful. Calling `runST` on an action produced by `unsafeIOtoST` is almost never safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how all of this works out in your actual code, and it seems to me that you're doing something more convoluted than strictly necessary, but as I can't say much definitive about that I'll only address the immediate problems in your question.

#### Why `testBar` doesn't work

In `(\(b,sf) -> extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo sf) <$> testBar'`, we have `<$>`, which has type `forall a b. (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b`. However, `testBar` has type `forall s. IO (Bool, ST s (Foo s))`. We can only apply `fmap` to `testBar` after the `s` there has been instantiated.

In your case, `s` is instantiated to a fresh variable `s0`, so inside the lambda `sf` also has that parameter. Unfortunately, `s0` is distinct from the topmost `s` parameter (which we'd like to see in the return type), so `sf` is pretty much unusable now.

In the case of `testFooBar`, the issue is that lambda arguments are monomorphic by default (or else type inference would become undecidable), so we just have to annotate the type:

```
testFooBar :: (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
testFooBar =
  (\(x :: forall s. (Bool, (ST s (Foo s)))) -> extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo $ snd x) testFooBar'
   where
      testFooBar' :: (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
      testFooBar' = extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo newFoo
```

All we've done here is to introduce an unwieldy alternative for `let` and `where` expressions. But this has little significance, since in `testFoo` the `fmap` necessitates that the lambda argument has a fully instantiated type, so there we can't annotate our woes away.

We might try the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

testBar :: forall s. IO (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
testBar = (\(b,sf) -> extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo sf) <$> testBar'
   where
      testBar' :: IO (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
      testBar' = return $ extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo newFoo
```

Now `testBar` has the right `s` parameter to begin with; since it's not generalized anymore, we can apply `fmap` to it right away. Inside the lambda, `sf` has type `ST s (Foo s)`. But this also doesn't work out, since `extractFoo` expects a `forall` quantified argument, and `sf` is monomorphic. Now - if you try this version in GHCi - the error message we get is no longer about escaping skolems, but a good old-fashioned `can't match type s with s2`.

#### How to help it

Clearly, `extract` must return a `forall s.`-ed `ST s (Foo s)` somehow. Your original type is no good because GHC doesn't have polymorphic return types, so

```
(forall s. ST s (Bool, Foo s)) -> (forall s. (Bool, ST s (Foo s)))
```

actually means

```
forall s. (forall s. ST s (Bool, Foo s)) -> (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
```

since GHC floats out all `forall`-s to the top of the scope. This makes type inference easier and allows more terms to typecheck. Indeed, you can enter `:t extract` in GHCi and be presented with the floated-out type.

A possible solution would be enabling `ImprediactiveTypes` and having

```
extract :: (forall s. ST s (Bool, Foo s)) -> (Bool, forall s. ST s (Foo s))
```

But there's a reason why `ImpredicativeTypes` is rarely used: it's poorly integrated with the rest of the type checking machinery and has a tendency to fail for all but the simplest purposes. As an example, assuming `extract` with the modified type, the following example doesn't typecheck:

```
testBar :: IO (Bool, forall s. ST s (Foo s))
testBar = (\(b, sf) -> (b, sf)) <$> testBar'
  where
    testBar' :: IO (Bool, forall s. ST s (Foo s))
    testBar' = return $ extractFoo $ splitChangeFoo newFoo
```

But it does typecheck when we change `(\(b, sf) -> (b, sf))` to `(\x -> x)`! So let's forget about impredicative types.

The usual solution is to just wrap the quantified types in a newtype. This is a lot less flexible than impredicative types, but at least it works.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow

data Foo s = Foo { foo::Bool }
newtype ST' f = ST' {unST' :: forall s. ST s (f s)}

newFoo :: ST s (Foo s)
newFoo = return $ Foo False

splitChangeFoo :: ST s (Foo s) -> ST s (Bool, Foo s)
splitChangeFoo = fmap (\(Foo b) -> (b, Foo (not b)))

extract :: (forall s. ST s (Bool, Foo s)) -> (Bool, ST' Foo)
extract s = (runST $ fst <$> s, ST' $ snd <$> s)

testBar :: IO (Bool, ST s (Foo s))
testBar = (\(_, ST' s) -> second unST' $ extract $ splitChangeFoo s) <$>
          (return $ extract $ splitChangeFoo newFoo)
```

So, whenever you need to return quantified types, wrap it in a newtype, then unwrap as needed. You might want to stick to a common type argument scheme for you custom types (for example, always make the `s` parameter the last, so you can use a single `ST'` type for multiple to-be-wrapped types).