# Haskell crashes with runST and Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable

Tags: haskell, state-monad

While learning and experimenting the use of `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` with `runST` came up with this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UVM (unsafeNew, unsafeWrite, unsafeRead)
import Control.Monad.ST

test :: Int -> Int
test len = runST $ do
    vec <- UVM.unsafeNew (len - 1)
    let
        fill !i
            | i >= len  = sumVec 0 0
            | otherwise = do
                UVM.unsafeWrite vec i i
                fill (i + 1)
        sumVec !k !total
            | k >= len  = return total
            | otherwise = do
                x <- UVM.unsafeRead vec k
                sumVec (k + 1) (total + x)
    fill 0

testParent = test 5
```

If I run this, Haskell stops working. I came to this while trying to make this work:

```
test :: Int -> Int
test len = do
.
.
.
testParent = runST $ test 5
```

But with no success.

- Why does Haskell (7.8.3) crashes with the provided code?
- How can I compute the `test` function using `runST` but outside of `test`? Was reading at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition) but still not clear why it doesn't works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
vec <- UVM.unsafeNew (len - 1)
```

you are creating a vector of length `len-1`. But you are writing into indices 0 through `len-1` so you need a vector of length `len`.

Change that to `len` and it will work.

As to your second question, you can use `runST` like this:

```
-- test now begins with the `do` statement
test len = do
  vec <- UVM.unsafeNew len
  ...

main = print $ runST $ test 5
```

main now has to wrap the call to test in `runST`.

Comment: Ok. First part good. But second part, I don't want it on main, I want it on another function (testParent), how can unwrap this monad to get the `int`?

Comment: `runST` unwraps the value; `runST $ test 5` is just an `Int`, so you can say things like `let x = 3*(runST $ test 5)`

Comment: Why then `testParent = runST $ test 5` doesn't compile?

Comment: What's the definition of `test` now? What's the error message? If `testParent` calls `runST`, then `test` itself should _not_ call `runST` - it just begins with the `do` statement as I mention in see  answer. Perhaps this should be a separate question.

Comment: It's exactly as shown in the second code box of the question, where the three verticals dots ( . ) mean the the code is the same as in the first code box.

Comment: THis works for me: http://lpaste.net/114351 Without seeing your code or your error message I can't do much more for you.

Comment: Ok, I see why is working for you. you removed the type definition of the function `test :: Int -> Int`