# Trouble with ST's type in a transformer stack

Tags: haskell, types, monad-transformers

I am having some trouble dealing with the `forall` quantifier in `ST`'s type. The following (simplified) code sample works fine, producing the expected result.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST

return' :: a -> ST s a
return' = return

function :: a -> a
function x = runST $ do
               -- Some complicated expression eventually producing a result
               return' x
```

This is fine, if all I want to do is have `ST`. But in my computation, I want a state transformer computation that might also fail, so I attempt to add `ExceptT` to the stack.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Except

return' :: a -> ExceptT String (ST s) a
return' = return

function :: a -> Either String a
function x = runST . runExceptT $ do
               -- Some complicated expression that might fail
               return' x
```

Unfortunately, I get a rather bizarre error message.

```
example.hs:9:14:
    Couldn't match type `ST s0 (Either String a)'
                   with `forall s. ST s (Either String a)'
    Expected type: ST s0 (Either String a) -> Either String a
      Actual type: (forall s. ST s (Either String a))
                   -> Either String a
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a (bound at example.hs:9:10)
      function :: a -> Either String a (bound at example.hs:9:1)
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `runST'
    In the expression: runST . runExceptT
```

I have only a vague understanding of the rank-2 type used by `ST`, so I'm not really sure how to approach this error. How can I safely put `ST` at the bottom of a monad transformer stack without getting problems with the `forall`?

(For those curious, I'm using `ST` because I want my computation to use a mutable array and then freeze it at the end. That shouldn't be relevant to this problem, but this is why I can't simply use `State` instead)

Comment: `ST` uses RankN types, and type inference with those does not really work well. For instance `runST action` could be OK while `runST $ action` errors out. GHC devs have added a _hack_ in ithe inference engine to treat the latter as the former, but this only applies to `$`. If you use `.` or even a redefinition of `$`, things stop working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the `.` behind `runST` by `$`, and then you can use ordinary `return` instead of `return'` as well.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Except

function :: a -> Either String a
function x = runST $ runExceptT $ do
               return x

main = return ()
```

(At least for me this compiles, without problems.)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition) for the theory behind the error.