# Unwrapping the STT monad in a transformer stack?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-rank-types

This question is apparently related to the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654814/trouble-with-sts-type-in-a-transformer-stack) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468963/runst-and-function-composition).  Unfortunately, my requirement is slightly different to those questions, and the answers given don't apply to me.  I also don't really understand *why* `runST` fails to type check in these cases, which doesn't help.

My problem is this, I have one section of code that uses one monad stack, or rather a single monad:

```
import Control.Monad.Except
type KErr a = Except KindError a
```

Another section of code needs to integrate with this that wraps this within the [STT monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/STMonadTrans-0.3.3/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Trans.html):

```
type RunM s a = STT s (Except KindError) a
```

At the interface between these sections, I clearly need to wrap and unwrap the outer layer.  I've got the following function to work in the `KErr` -> `RunM` direction:

```
kerrToRun :: KErr a -> RunM s a
kerrToRun e = either throwError return $ runExcept e
```

but for some reason I just can't get the converse to type check:

```
runToKErr :: RunM s a -> KErr a
runToKErr r = runST r
```

I'm working on the assumption that as the `RunM`'s inner monad has the same structure as `KErr`, I can just return it once I've unwrapped the `STT` layer, but I don't seem to be able to get that far, as `runST` complains about its type arguments:

```
src/KindLang/Runtime/Eval.hs:18:21:
    Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘s1’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for runToKErr :: RunM s a -> KErr a
          at src/KindLang/Runtime/Eval.hs:17:14
      ‘s1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context:
             STT s1 (ExceptT KindError Data.Functor.Identity.Identity) a
           at src/KindLang/Runtime/Eval.hs:18:15
    Expected type: STT
                     s1 (ExceptT KindError Data.Functor.Identity.Identity) a
      Actual type: RunM s a
```

I've also tried:

```
runToKErr r = either throwError return $ runExcept $ runST r
```

in order to more strongly isolate `runST` from its expected return type, in case that was the cause of the issue, but the results are the same.

Where is this `s1` type coming from, and how do I persuade ghc that it's the same type as `s`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(The below talks about `ST s a` but applies just the same as `STT s m a`; I've just avoided the unnecessary complication of talking about the transformer version below)

The problem you are seeing is that `runST` has type `(forall s. ST s a) -> a` to isolate any potential (`STRef`-changing) effects of the computation from the outside, pure world. The whole point of the `s` phantom type that all `ST` computations, `STRef`s, etc. are tagged with, is to track which "`ST`-domain" they belong to; and the type of `runST` ensures that nothing can pass between domains.

You can write `runToKErr` by enforcing the same invariant:

```
{-# language Rank2Types #-}

runToKErr :: (forall s. RunM s a) -> KErr a
runToKErr = runST
```

(of course, you might realize further down the road that this restriction is too strong for the program you hope to write; at that point you'll need to lose hope, sorry, I mean you'll need to redesign your program.)

As for the error message, the reason you can't "convince the type checker that `s1` and `s` are the same type" is because if I pass you an `ST s a` for a given choice of `s` and `a`, that is not the same as giving you something which allows you to choose your own `s`. GHC chose `s1` (a [Skolemized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) variable) as `s` and so tries to unify `ST s a` with `ST s1 a`