# Why doesn't forall (RankNTypes usage) apply by default?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am not so familiar with `forall`, but recently read this question: [What does the `forall` keyword in Haskell/GHC do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071136/what-does-the-forall-keyword-in-haskell-ghc-do)

In one of the answers is this example:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
 liftTup :: (forall x. x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
 liftTup liftFunc (t, v) = (liftFunc t, liftFunc v)
```

The explanation is good and I understand what `forall` is doing here. But I'm wondering, is there a particular reason why this isn't the default behaviour. Is there ever a time where it would be disadvantageous?

Edit: I mean, is there are a reason why the forall's can't be inserted by default?

Comment: Are you asking why the extension isn't on by default or why `(x -> f x) -> (a,b) -> (f a, f b)` isn't treated the same as `(forall x. x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)`? If it's the latter, can you specify the logic by which you propose the compiler should decide where to insert the `forall`s?

Comment: The latter, and I wouldn't know where to begin proposing anything at all on this subject!

Comment: Note that the type `(x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)` is fairly useless. The function can't apply the first argument to either element of the tuple, so its result must be either `⊥` or `(⊥, ⊥)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, it's not part of the Haskell 2010 standard, so it's not on by default, and is offered as a language extension instead. As for why it's not in the standard, rank-n types are quite a bit harder to implement than the plain rank-1 types standard Haskell has; they're also not needed all that frequently, so the Committee likely decided not to bother with them for reasons of language and implementation simplicity.

Of course, that doesn't mean rank-n types aren't useful; they are, very much so, and without them we wouldn't have valuable tools like the [`ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html) (which offers efficient, local mutable state — like `IO` where all you can do is use `IORef`s). But they do add quite a bit of complexity to the language, and can cause strange behaviour when applying seemingly benign code transformations. For instance, some rank-n type checkers will allow `runST (do { ... })` but reject `runST $ do { ... }`, even though the two expressions are always equivalent without rank-n types. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343239/type-error-with-rank-2-types-and-function-composition) for an example of the unexpected (and sometimes annoying) behaviour it can cause.

If, like sepp2k asks, you're instead asking why `forall` has to be explicitly added to type signatures to get the increased generality, the problem is that `(forall x. x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)` is actually a more restrictive type than `(x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)`. With the latter, you can pass in any function of the form `x -> f x` (for any `f` and `x`), but with the former, the function you pass in must work for *all* `x`. So, for instance, a function of type `String -> IO String` would be a permissible argument to the second function, but not the first; it'd have to have the type `a -> IO a` instead. It would be pretty confusing if the latter was automatically transformed into the former! They're two very different types.

It might make more sense with the implicit `forall`s made explicit:

```
forall f x a b. (x -> f x)           -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
forall f a b.   (forall x. x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
```

Comment: I think I need to digest this some more :)

Comment: Also, for second and higher order polymorphism, there's no such thing as the most general type, `∀ b. (∀ a. a → b) → (b, b)` isn't more general than `∀ c d. (∀ a b. a → b) → (c, d)` nor the other way around. And while type inference is decidable for first and second order polymorphism, it is not for third and higher.

Comment: @vitus - can you provide a reference for decidability of second order polymorphism?  I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @JohnL: I've found it in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), which in turn references Pierce's Types and Programming Languages.

Comment: @JohnL: It should be in chapter 23.8. (rank 2 polymorphism restriction of System F): Kfoury and Wells (1999) gave the first correct type reconstruction
algorithm for the rank 2 system and showed that type reconstruction
for ranks 3 and higher of System F is undecidable.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that higher rank types aren't enabled by default because [they make type inference undecidable](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types).  This is also why, even with the extension enabled, you need to use the `forall` keyword to get a higher-rank type - GHC assumes that all types are rank-1 unless explicitly told otherwise in order to infer as much type information as possible.

Put another way, there's no general way to infer a higher-rank type `(forall x. x -> f x) -> (a,b) -> (f a, f b)`, so the only way to get that type is by an explicit type signature.

Edit: per Vitus's comments above, rank-2 type inference is decidable, but higher-rank polymorphism isn't.  So this type signature is technically inferrable (although the algorithm is more complex).  Whether the extra complexity of enabling rank-2 polymorphic type inference is worthwhile is debatable...