# GHC type inference for higher rank types - assigning to monotypes

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I previously asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345809/haskell-rank-two-polymorphism-compile-error), and after much investigation I concluded that there are special rules GHC applies only for infix `$` and `.`.

For this question, I'm assuming that GHC follows the system mentioned on the [RankNTypes - Haskell Prime](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RankNTypes) page further elaborated in the [arbitary-rank](http://research.microsoft.com/Users/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/).

[RankNTypes - Haskell Prime](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RankNTypes) page states the following:

> parameter variables without explicit signatures are assigned
>   monotypes in upwards inference, but may inherit arbitrary-rank types
>   in downwards checking.

I'm presuming "assigned monotypes" means that rank-N types are converted to rank-1 types by moving all their qualifiers to the outermost level.

I also believe this is what caused the unusual type error that led to me asking my previous question.

So I have a few questions:

1) Is there anyway to get GHC to warn (or error) on implicit conversion to monotypes? The type error in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345809/haskell-rank-two-polymorphism-compile-error) took a while to work out, a warning of a conversion to monotype would have been more helpful than a type error.
2) Are there cases where implicit "assigning to monotypes" is sensible behaviour, and if so, could you give an example?
3) Regarding infix `$` and `.`, these seem to have special rules in GHC. Where is this documented? And are there any other special rules that GHC has, and where are they documented?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9468963/775806) could be of interest.

Comment: As to point 3, my suspicion is that they're only documented in the GHC source.  I'm not aware of any documentation at any rate.  You might try asking on the ghc-users list for an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5596 is relevant here - I don't think there's any official documentation.